# Conditional column value calculation, zip code to lat/long

Tags: r, conditional-statements, geocoding, boolean-logic

I need help trying to figure out how to do this in R. I don't know how to generate latitude and longitude from zip code data so I am stuck on the first part.

I have a df that looks like:

| ID | ZIP code | loc 1 zip code | loc 2 zip code | loc 3 zip code | Opinion on loc 1 | Opinion on loc 2 | Opinion on loc 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90804 | 91723 | 90814 | 91604 | Neutral | Like | Dislike |

I am trying to add three columns that look like this:

| ID | ZIP code | loc 1 zip code | loc 2 zip code | loc 3 zip code | Opinion on loc 1 | Opinion on loc 2 | Opinion on loc 3 | Distance from Like | Distance from Disike | Distance from Neutral |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90804 | 91723 | 90814 | 91604 | Neutral | Like | Dislike | 42 Km | 56 Km | 24 Km |

I only have the zip code data, I am trying to know if there is a way to create columns for longitude and latitude so that distance calculation is possible.

After that, the columns that need to be created need to first match which location does the customer 'Like', calculate their distance from it, and then put the distance in the 'Distance from Like' column and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If it are USA zipcodes, use library zipcodeR which directly allows you to calculate distances between zipcodes

```
library(zipcodeR)
zip_distance(zipcode_a, zipcode_b, lonlat = TRUE, units = "meters")
```

Comment: That's awesome! Do you have any tips for creating the columns based on what the answer they gave was?