# Function for calculating based on condition from value from different columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I need help trying to figure out how to do this in R.

I have a df that looks like:

| ID | ZIP code | loc 1 zip code | loc 2 zip code | loc 3 zip code | Opinion on loc 1 | Opinion on loc 2 | Opinion on loc 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90804 | 91723 | 90814 | 91604 | Neutral | Like | Dislike |

I am trying to add three columns that look like this:

| ID | ZIP code | loc 1 zip code | loc 2 zip code | loc 3 zip code | Opinion on loc 1 | Opinion on loc 2 | Opinion on loc 3 | Distance from Like | Distance from Disike | Distance from Neutral |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90804 | 91723 | 90814 | 91604 | Neutral | Like | Dislike | 42 Km | 56 Km | 24 Km |

The columns that need to be created need to first match which location does the customer 'Like', calculate their distance from it, and then put the distance in the 'Distance from Like' column and so on.

I am using this function to calculate the distance:

```r
library(zipcodeR)
zip_distance(zipcode_a, zipcode_b, lonlat = TRUE, units = "meters")
```

(Credit: First answer on [Conditional column value calculation, zip code to lat/long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044692/conditional-column-value-calculation-zip-code-to-lat-long))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your column names so that they are consistently formatted with location_variable then you can use tidyr's pivot_long to get everything into long format, and then you can calculate all the distances as the zip codes for all locations are now in a column. You can then either leave it as a long data format or wrangle it back to the wide format you requested

```
library(tidyverse)
test<- read.table( text = "ID,UserZIPcode,loc1_zipcode,loc2_zipcode,loc3_zipcode,loc1_Opinion,loc2_Opinion,loc3_Opinion
1,1,90804,91723,90814,91604,Neutral,Like,Dislike", sep = "," )

test_distances <- test %>% 
        pivot_longer(cols = c(-ID, -UserZIPcode), names_pattern  = "(.*)_(.*)", names_to = c("location",".value")) %>% 
        mutate(Distance = zip_distance(UserZIPcode, zipcode, lonlat = TRUE, units = "meters"))
  


test_distances %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = Opinion, names_prefix = "Distance_from", values_from = "Distance") %>% 
  right_join(test)
```